# Define prerequisites for a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying to create a class with lesson concepts that can store values that a lesson in school needs. One of those values is the university course (or maybe it shouldn't be a value or it should be an inherited class or nested class. I'm not sure) which includes three degrees Bachelor(BS), Master(MS), and Doctorate(PHD). There is a number for each lesson and the beginning of the numbers is different for each degree. Bachelor's degree number starts at 1000, Master's degree number starts at 2000, and Doctorate number starts at 3000, They are created automatically when the class is created. The number of units for each lesson is also determined, which should be a number between 1 and 4 and by default, it is 3.
Now my problem is two things. First, the new class should be defined as follows, but I don't know how to do this.

```
// course is my main class
new course(course.PHD) /* Create a lesson in PHD degree */
new course(course.BS, "My Lesson Name") /* Create a lesson in BS degree */
new course(course.PHD, "My Lesson Name", 3) /* Create a lesson in MS degree, 3 is the number of course units */
```

Second, one lesson can be a prerequisite for another, and a prerequisite must be a different lesson, but from the same degree. A prerequisite is defined as follows:

```
course1.SetPreRequisite(course2) /* course2 is defined as a prerequisite for course1. */
```

This is my code:

```
class course
{
public:
    course(string name_, int unit_)
    {
        this->name = name_;
        if (unit_ >= 1 && unit_ <= 4)
        {
            this->unit = unit_;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "unit numbers is not valid. So I will set uni number as default.";
            this->unit = 3;
        }
    }
    void SetPreRequisite(course);
private:
    course PreRequisite();
    string name;
    int unit;
};
class BS : course
{
public:
    BS(string name_, int unit_) : course(name_, unit_)
    {
        num = ++_num;
    }
private:
    int num;
    static int _num;
};
class MS : course
{
public:
    MS(string name_, int unit_) : course(name_, unit_)
    {
        this->num = ++_num;
    }
private:
    int num;
    static int _num;
};
class PHD : course
{
public:
    PHD(string name_, int unit_) : course(name_, unit_)
    {
        this->num = ++_num;
    }
private:
    int num;
    static int _num;
};

int BS::_num = 999;
int MS::_num = 1999;
int PHD::_num = 2999;
void course::SetPreRequisite(course PreRequisote_)
{
    this->PreRequisite = PreRequisote_; /* Error (active)   E0300   a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function temporary */
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: don't use `new` to create objects when you don't have to. You (almost) never have to.

Comment: `course PreRequisite();` is a (member) function declaration, not a regular member, you probably want `const course* PreRequisite;` and (`void SetPreRequisite(const course*);`)

Comment: Thank you Jarod42. It worked and the error is gone. but I didn't understand why should I use const???

Comment: `const` as I don't want to mutate course from the dependent courses. (I (try to) default to `const` (like Rust) until I need mutation).

Comment: Jarod42, Thank you.